# Доставка по городу

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть сайт на wordpress, необходимо сделать расчет стоимости доставки в зависимости от расстояния и от суммы заказа(если покупатель набрал товаров на нужную сумму, то доставка бесплатна). Доставка осуществляется курьером. Имеются ли готовые плагины для этой цели?

Comment: Нужно, сделайте.

Comment: @by Verng, может уже есть готовые плагины?